# How can I generate SHA3 if there is no sha3sum command in coreutils?

Tags: linux, hashsum, bsd, checksum

I have `sha1sum` or `sha512sum` on an average Linux distro.

But where is the `sha3sum` command that can generate[SHA-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3) commands?

Answer (score 33):

You can use [**OpenSSL**](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-dgst.html) to do this. Run `openssl list -digest-algorithms` to get a list of algorithms:

```
...
SHA3-224
SHA3-256
SHA3-384
SHA3-512
...
```

As you can see `sha3-{224,256,384,512}` is supported by OpenSSL 1.1.1 (11 Sep 2018) from Ubuntu 18.10.
You can also run `openssl` interactively:

```
OpenSSL> help
...
Message Digest commands (see the `dgst' command for more details)
blake2b512        blake2s256        gost              md4               
md5               rmd160            sha1              sha224            
sha256            sha3-224          sha3-256          sha3-384          
sha3-512          sha384            sha512            sha512-224        
sha512-256        shake128          shake256          sm3
```

To checksum a file:

```
openssl dgst -sha3-512 /bin/echo
SHA3-512(/bin/echo)= c9a3baaa2aa3d667a4ff475d893b3e84eb588fb46adecd0af5f3cdd735be88c62e179f98dc8275955da4ee5ef1dc7968620686c6f7f63f5b80f10e43bc1f00fc
```

To checksum a string:

```bsh
printf "foobar" | openssl dgst -sha3-512
```

You can change the output format with these options:

- `-c` Print out the digest in two digit groups separated by colons
- `-r` Output the digest in the "coreutils" format, including newlines

Comment: Note, for all the people who are using `echo` with this and are wondering why they cant get correct results: ensure to pass `-n` to avoid the newline-pitfall

Comment: I've tried "printf "foobar" | openssl dgst -sha3-512", got unknown option '-sha3-512'. openssl LibreSSL 2.8.3

Comment: @lebed2045 LibreSSL does not support SHA-3.

Comment: @lebed2045 [LibreSSL issue for adding support for SHA-3](https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/issues/455)

Answer (score 21):

There are a number of implementations, *e.g.* [Mattias Andrée's `sha3sum`](https://github.com/maandree/sha3sum), or the [Perl Digest-SHA3 module](https://metacpan.org/release/Digest-SHA3). In Debian, install `libdigest-sha3-perl`; in Fedora, install `sha3sum`; both of these will provide a `sha3sum` command based on the Perl module, which behaves in the same way as the binaries you're used to.

Answer (score 13):

[**RHash**](https://github.com/rhash/RHash.git) application could do it:

```
rhash --sha3-256 yourfile
```

More info: `rhash -h`

it will work on Linux, BSD and Windows

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, [Busybox has had code for it](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/log/?qt=grep&q=sha3) since 2013.

Comment: But since the final SHA3 specification was not released by NIST until August 5 2015, Busybox's implementation must have been based on preliminary versions of the spec... and so Busybox [needed a fix in 2016 in order to conform to the final version of the SHA3 algorithm specification](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/commit/?id=71a090f1871f165ebf3c31f733b36aafca71a6b4).

Answer (score 3):

If you're lazy like me and are used to md5sum, sha1sum, sha256sum:

Create the file /usr/local/bin/sha3256sum and make it executable with chmod +x sha3256sum.

```
#!/bin/bash
rhash --sha3-256 $1
```

Then you can run:

```
sha3256sum file
```

Comment: Alternatively, a simple alias would suffice: `alias sha3256sum="rhash --sha3-256"`.  That  can also go into your `~/.bash_aliases` or `~/.bash_profile` or some place appropriate for your shell.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is sha3sum for Linux, BSD, Windows, Mac,.... All platforms supported by Rust.

For Rust users:  `cargo install sha3sum`

Further details are available with a [wiki](https://gitlab.com/kurdy/sha3sum/-/wikis/home).

**Note**: I am the author of this tool.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `openssl` installed you should have the `hashalot` command which says :

> ```
>    Supported values for HASHTYPE:
>            ripemd160 rmd160 rmd160compat sha256 sha384 sha512
> ```

<strike>You can also use directly the `sha384` command.</strike>

A recent enough version of OpenSSL (1.1.1 or later) has full SHA-3 support, `openssl help` will show:

```
Message Digest commands (see the `dgst' command for more details)
blake2b512        blake2s256        gost              md4
md5               mdc2              rmd160            sha1
sha224            sha256            sha3-224          sha3-256
sha3-384          sha3-512          sha384            sha512
sha512-224        sha512-256        shake128          shake256
sm3
```

Comment: updating the question, sha384 is sha2. sha3 is not sha2.

Comment: yes indeed, sorry for my mistake. Support for SHA3 in `openssl` is planned/in the work : https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/439